# How long have you met him?

Tags: present-perfect

So I was helping my friend with her English and she asked me to explain this question:

**When did you first meet him?
-> How long have you met him?**

I know the form
**When did + Subject + first + Verb => How long have/has + Subject + Past Participle** is correct but I just think the sentence **How long have you met him** sounds a little bit wrong and I just want to explain it correctly to her so if anyone can help me check if the sentence is correct and explain it to me I'd be very thankful.

Comment: The formula "When did + Subject + first + Verb => How long have/has + Subject + Past Participle" only works when the activity is ongoing. "When did you first swim? How long have you swum?" "Meeting" someone is an activity that can't go on indefinitely.

Comment: *How long have you **known** him?* references the *continuous* process of *knowing* someone. *How long **ago did** you **meet** him?* references the ***point in past time*** (in terms of an offset from "now") at which the *completed* action of *meeting* someone took place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first meeting with someone is a one-off occasion; you can't use it with *how long have you?*. Your friend needs to say "How long have you *known* him?"

Comment: You could also ask "[For] how long did you meet with him?", if you wanted to know whether that particular occasion lasted a long time or not.  I agree that the intention is to find out how long ago that meeting was.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle "meet with" and "meet" do not mean the same thing.